# Angular Material Nested Column Height Calculation

Tags: html, css, flexbox, angular-material

**Update**

*It seems the expected behavior occurs in the latest Firefox and Edge - this might be a problem exclusive to Chrome (can't believe I typed that...)*

[Here](http://codepen.io/don_carron/pen/vLWKzO?editors=110) is a codepen that illustrates the problem. And here is the code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="thingone" layout="column" flex="100" layout-fill>
    <div class="thingtwo" layout="column" flex="75">
      <div class="thingfour" layout="column" flex="25"></div>
      <div class="thingfive" layout="column" flex="75"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="thingthree" layout="column" flex="25"></div>  
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.thingone {
  background-color: red;
}
.thingtwo {
  background-color: blue;
  border: 10px solid black;
}
.thingthree {
  background-color: green;
  border: 10px solid white;
}
.thingfour {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.thingfive {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

My end goal is to see three total bars - the first two wrapped in a bar that takes up 75% of the parent's available area and the last one taking up only 25% of the parent's available area. The first two bars should take up 25% and 75% of their parent's area respectively.

As you can see from the codepen I am close but the child columns aren't respecting their 25% and 75% flex assignments. As a simple example I am struggling to understand why.

Ideally I'd like a solution that doesn't involve rows (as the real UI this example is modeled after requires columns) unless the columns are nested within rows.

Perhaps more importantly still - what's an easy way to explain what is happening here? Is there a 'rule' one must apply when dealing with nested columns in flex (such as always providing explicit height assignments to parent elements)?

Thanks!

Comment: Downvotes are fine when they are paired with some kind of constructive comment. I searched for other questions related to this one and found nothing directly related. What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to the problem was to not use the 'layout-fill' attribute on the 'thingtwo' element when attempting to have a element fill the available vertical space. 'layout-fill' specifies the min-height CSS attribute in addition to the height attribute which appears to be causing the layout problem.

Here's the solution for those that stumble upon a similar issue:

**HTML**

```
<div class="thingone" layout="column" flex="100">
    <div class="thingtwo" layout="column" flex="75">
      <div class="thingfour" layout="column" flex="25"></div>
      <div class="thingfive" layout="column" flex="75"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="thingthree" layout="column" flex="25"></div>  
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.thingone {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
}
.thingtwo {
  background-color: blue;
  border: 10px solid black;
  height: 100%;
}
.thingthree {
  background-color: green;
  border: 10px solid white;
}
.thingfour {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.thingfive {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

Comment: Or you can manually set the `flex: 1/3` CSS and leave the `height` out of it, which may be better cross-browser: http://codepen.io/kuhnroyal/pen/dGZdYV

Comment: @kuhnroyal Thanks for the comment! I do like your solution but it's a bit of a bummer to not be using material's flex attributes at all in that case. Given that angular-material is out of beta I was hoping to rely on it a bit more.